# How can I get some attributes of my object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am coding using Django framework and I'm stuck at this issue:

```
usercomment = 'Test'
usercomments = json.dumps(usercomment)
data = {
    'date': '2019-02-06',
    'usercomments': usercomments,
    'totalminutes': '120',
    'searched': 'functionTest'
}
```

At this line, I create the entry in the database.

```
response = self.client.post("/urlRegistration/", data=data, follow=True)
```

But when I want to get the unique-id of the object created in the database I cannot because the connection is closed

```
myObject = Myobject.objects.filter(usercomment=usercomment)
uniqueid = myObject[0].uniqueid
```

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much!

Edit : Python told me this :

```
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

For the variable response I get : `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "application/json">`

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback here?

Comment: Most likely the variable `response` must contain the unique-id of the record being submitted in the database. But that entirely depends on the API design. Can you show what is coming back in `response` variable?